# Помочь решить задачу по Ruby("Зачисление студентов")

Tags: ruby

Здравствуйте.
Все никак не могу найти решение одной задачи по Ruby (для начинающих).
А именно не понимаю какую команду использовать.
Буду рад если оптимизируете код и укажете на ошибки)
Заранее благодарю)

Вот задача :

```
    studenti = {
  2009 => 512,
  2010 => 575,
  2011 => 568,
  2012 => 631
}
```

И ответ должен быть такой:

```
Количество лет, включенных в статистику: **4**
В те годы насчитывалось более 600 студентов:
**{2012 => 631}**
Число студентов увеличилось на 10:
**[522, 585, 578, 641]**
```

А вот мое решение, которое не получилось завершить и возможно сделаны ошибки:

```
    # coding: utf-8
studenti = {
  2009 => 512,
  2010 => 575,
  2011 => 568,
  2012 => 631
}
a = studenti.sort_by {|k,v|} [0] [0]
b = studenti.sort_by {|k,v|} [-1] [0]
c = 1
x = b - a + c
puts "Количество лет, включенных в статистику:" + x.to_s
puts "В те годы насчитывалось более 600 студентов:"
p studenti.reject {|k,v| v < 600}
puts "Число студентов увеличилось на 10:"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
puts "Количество лет, включенных в статистику: #{studenti.count}"
puts "В те годы насчитывалось более 600 студентов:"
puts studenti.select{ |k,v| v > 600}.to_s
puts "Число студентов увеличилось на 10:"
puts studenti.map{ |k,v| v+=10}.to_s
```

Comment: Здравствуйте.
Спасибо вам большое за решение)я был близок, но делал ошибку в написании(т.к "гадал")Все получилось!)

Answer (score 1):

"Команду"? Простите, вы на лекциях-то были?
Погуглите "`rdoc Enumerable`", и там посмотрите `select`, `size`, `map`.
Научитесь пользоваться `irb`.

Хотя, как тут сказал один коллега, что нужно таким, как вы помогать. Тогда нам, опытным, всегда будут так много платить.

Comment: Здравствуйте.
Спасибо вам большое за ответ, я обязательно все повторю, очень много интересного в Enumerable", но пока что я новиче и тяжеловато лично для меня))
Да именно в этом и дело, на лекции я не ходил)теперь нагоняю)